# Will diskpart clean destroy existing data?

Tags: diskpart

I am downgrading a laptop from windows 8 to windows 7, but in order to do so I have to use `diskpart clean`. The disk has several partitions, namely a system partition and a data partition.

Will `diskpart clean` destroy the existing data in the data partition?

Comment: If you don't clean the data partition you will not lose data, but before doing _any_ partition modifications you have to be prepared to lose your entire disc, so you **must** create a disc image before you embark on this sort of task: it is very easy to make mistakes, as I know all too well. To make recovery easier, take a separate copy of your data partition. You cannot have too many back-ups.

Comment: Damned windows 8 is like a tick. Can't install windows 7 on a gpt partition, the partition with the install is already formatted, now I'm xcopying the files on a flash drive under command prompt so I can `diskpart clean`...

Comment: "Can't install windows 7 on a GPT partition" - You do realize that it actually is possible to install Windows 7 on a GPT partition right?

Comment: @Ramhound - the installer says it can't. The how-to's I found all include the `diskpart clean` step.

Comment: Your booting the installation in UEFI mode, and trying to install a 64-bit version of Windows 7, if both of those are true Windows 7 supports GPT. "the installer says it can't. " - doesn't tell me anything, provide the exact message, I am telling you Windows 7 supports GPT.

Comment: @Ramhound - will see about that after I make a backup, just in case.

Comment: @Ramhound the problem is that the USB flash doesn't show up without CSM, so it tries to install in legacy bios mode.

Comment: If a USB 2.0 flash drive isn't showing up unless you enable CSM then its not configured to be a EFI drive.  Use Rufus to create it

Comment: That's what I am doing now, I've already done it actually, but for some reason after I select gpt and then select the image, the partition scheme resets back to mbr, which I didn't notice the first time.

Comment: @Ramhound - and it never ends. Now the flash is recognized as uefi bootable, but "windows failed to start blah blah recent hardware or software change..." : efi/microsoft/boot/bcd  status: 0xc00000d  - an error occurred while attempting to read the boot configuration data.

Comment: You need to format the drive, so there are no partitions on the drive, before you attempt to install Windows.  I hope you understand that, there isn't a mechanic to go from Windows 8 to Windows 7, unless you format the drive.  All your other solution does would allow Windows 7 to install in Legacy Mode, and you would end up with MBR partitions.

Comment: @Ramhound - I have formatted the system partition. The idea here is to keep the data partition in tact. I was able to boot from the flash in csm mode, and despite a warning about gpt it is now installing, hopefully that will work.

Comment: "The idea here is to keep the data partition in tact." - Can you migrate the data to another drive, do as I suggest install Windows on the unallocated partition, then create the data partition after Windows 7 is installed?  You currently have a GPT or MBR HDD?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51378/discussion-between-ddriver-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 2):

#### Will diskpart clean destroy the existing data in the data partition?

`diskpart clean` will remove any and all partition or volume formatting from the disk with focus.

`diskpart clean all` will zero the disk.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [diskpart](http://ss64.com/nt/diskpart.html) - Disk Administration, Partition a disk.

Answer (score 0):

No, `diskpart clean` won't destroy the data, it just deletes the partition table. You can recover the lost partitions using the excellent **testdisk** utility, by using testdisk's "Quick Scan" feature. **Testdisk** comes preinstalled on the [GParted LiveCD](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd)

*Also avoid the <del>"Minitool"</del> worthless recovery tool which has pages with harmful advice on how to destroy your partitions and then tries to sell you their scam recovery tool to get the partitions back.*

To convert MBR partitions to GPT, use the gdisk tool which is also found on the GParted LiveCD.

Comment: Note that clearing the partition information effectively deletes all the data. You WILL end up having to recover the data after performing a clean.